# Django import into many to many relationship with custom through table

Tags: django, import, many-to-many

I am not sure the proper way to import using django-import-export tsv files into many to many relationship tables.  What I have done is create a books table, a genre table and a bookgenre through table which contains the foreignkeys to each of the other tables.  So what I have is:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class BookGenre(models.Model):
    book_id = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre_id = models.ForeignKey('Genre', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then I import all three tables and the relationships are working but I can't figure out a way to make a view or template that works effectively.  I am thinking there must be a better way to create a many to many relationship and import data into it.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a pivot table, use [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationships.

**UPDATE**
You do not create a `m2m` model, but a `many-to-many` relationship that points to a specific model. Below is the implementation.

```
class Abc(models.Model):
    field = models.TextField()

class Xyz(models.Model):
    other_field = models.TextField()
    m2m_field = models.ManyToManyField(Abc)
```

If you want to get related data, you will use:

`object_xyz.abcs.all()`
or `object_abc.xyz_set.all()`

As I wrote earlier, you can find more detailed information in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: If I create a many to many model, say books has a many to many field linking to genres, how do I import data into it?  How does it establish the links?

Comment: Check the updated answer.